# How can I code an algorithm (concerning networks)

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming

my question is basic but I want to know how to code algorithms containing maths like this https://web.stanford.edu/~skatti/pubs/sigcomm15-spotfi.pdf , TY for your help !

Comment: This is not really a complete algorithm. It's a sketch of an algorithm. Presumably, the same paper containing this sketch also contains more details, and the rest you'll have to work out on your own. Perhaps they're being vague on purpose.

Comment: Your question is impossibly general. What, specifically, stops you from implementing the algorithm sketched here?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: @Raphael Isn't the real problem here that the question is about coding? Sure, text as images is bad, but I don't see any point asking the user to transcribe that image to text when the resulting question is still off-topic. That's just a waste of their time.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I saw potential for an on-topic and not-too-broad question there, for example if the OP focused on a single step and could articulate a specific question. Filling in algorithmic gaps in high-level pseudo code feels potentially ontopic for me, at least.

Comment: @Raphael OK, I can see the question being on-topic if it was changed in that direction, though that would seem to be quite a big change.